# sql convert rows into columns in sql server 2008r2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a tables called customer, hobby's.
A customer has several hobby's. So if I join my table customer with table hobby I get a result like:

```
[CustomerName]    [HobbyName]
Harry              Tennis
Harry              Football
```

What I would like is to see a result like this:

```
[CustomerName]    [HobbyName1]    [HobbyName2]
Harry              Tennis           Football
```

My current query looks like this:

```
  Select tCustomer.name, tHobby.name 
    from dbo.customer    tCustomer
    inner join dbo.hobby tHobby on tHobby.customerid = tCustomer.id
```

Comment: You may want to look up Pivot.

Comment: Is it required to be converted into a one-to-one relationship, or are you just looking to get a group of hobbies for each CustomerName?

Comment: What if Harry has another hobby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You didn't provide many details on your table structure but you can use PIVOT to get the final result, but in order to use this you will first want to use `row_number()` to generate a unique sequence for each hobby per customer:

```
select customer, Hobby1, Hobby2
from
(
  Select c.name customer, 
    h.name hobby,
    'Hobby'+
      cast(row_number() over(partition by c.id 
                             order by h.name) as varchar(10)) seq
  from dbo.customer c
  inner join dbo.hobby h 
    on h.customerid = c.id
) d
pivot
(
  max(hobby)
  for seq in (hobby1, Hobby2)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67403/2).  If you don't want to use the PIVOT function, then you could also use a CASE expression and an aggregate function:

```
select customer,
  max(case when seq = 1 then hobby end) hobby1,
  max(case when seq = 2 then hobby end) hobby2
from
(
  Select c.name customer, 
    h.name hobby,
    row_number() over(partition by c.id 
                      order by h.name) seq
  from dbo.customer c
  inner join dbo.hobby h 
    on h.customerid = c.id
) d
group by customer;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/67403/4)

Comment: wow thx I chosefor the method with a CASE expression. Thank you for resolving this for me.